# How to sort sections without class/div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to achieve using jQuery probably is to rearrange the positions of the following sections on page load, in 2 ways. The first is to sort it by data-order value ascending, and the other through an array where it will be in this sorting 3-1-2

How can this be achieved?

```
<section class="aboutus" data-order="1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p>content here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="questions" data-order="3">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p>content here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="contact" data-order="2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p>content here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I found this code that uses an array for this, however it requires specific classes, but I want it to be as universal as possible, no classes or ids.

```
var myArray = ['2', '3', '1'];
var elArray = [];

$('.imgs').each(function() {
    elArray[$(this).data('image-id')] = $(this);
});

$.each(myArray,function(index,value){
   $('#container').append(elArray[value]); 
});
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
   <div class="imgs" data-image-id='1'>1</div>
   <div class="imgs" data-image-id='2'>2</div>
   <div class="imgs" data-image-id='3'>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not certain interpret second sort correctly ? Add items to array based on `data-order` , though sorted `data-order="3"` , `data-order="1"`,  `data-order="2"` ?

Comment: @guest271314 Hi, I am aware of the logic, however I am not able to do the development because all of the code examples I find are stricted to classes and ids

Comment: Yes, not certain about second portion of requirement. Is second portion of requirement to populate array `elArray` with elements in `data-order` 3, 1, 2 ?

Comment: @guest271314 exactly, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
// elements
var elems = $("[data-order]");
// ordering map
var elArray = ["3", "1", "2"];
// replace `elems` `outerHTML`
$.map(elArray, function(order, i) {
  var el = elems.filter(function() {
    // ie < 11 does not appear to support `dataset`
    // jQuery `.data()` appear to cast `String` "3" to `Number` `3`
    // utilize equality operator `==` to convert operands 
    return $(this).data("order") == order
  });
  elems.eq(i)[0].outerHTML = el[0].outerHTML
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="aboutus" data-order="1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p>content here 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="questions" data-order="3">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p>content here 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="contact" data-order="2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p>content here 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/saf77L4w/4/

Comment: How does this work? It supposed to put it in 3-1-2 position but it is just sorting it asc

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos That is portion asked about at comments above.  _"The first is to sort it by data-order value ascending, and the other through an array where it will be in this sorting 3-1-2"_ ? Not entirely clear, here. elements appended to document in order 1-2-3 ?,  `elArray`  in order 3-1-2  ?

Comment: Thank you for the update but still.. I have placed the code here http://jsfiddle.net/saf77L4w/ for a live environment, when I change the data-order from the HTML to 1-2-3, and the array to 2-1-3, I still get 3-1-2

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos Try changing the "content here 1", "content here 2", "content here 3" within `html` to correspond to the element `data-order` attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/saf77L4w/1/ . At http://jsfiddle.net/saf77L4w/  `html` "content here 3" appear at `data-order="2"` element; "content here 2" appear at `data-order="3"` element . If inspect elements at `console`  , `data-order` of elements appear 2-1-3

Comment: You can see that in 3-1-2 nothing is changed. I want the section 3 to be placed on top, then 1, then 2

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the element just using their `data-sort` attribute (although this will place all items on the page in the same sorted list, so you would have to restrict this if you wanted to use it multiple times on a page).

```
var elArray = [];

$('[data-order]').each(function() {
    elArray[$(this).data('order')] = this;
});

for(var i = 0; i < elArray.length; i++) {
    if (typeof elArray[i] === 'undefined') continue;
    $('#result').append(elArray[i]); 
}
```

I have added an element with the id "result" to place the sorted items in - but you can do this differently if you wish.

See it [running on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6oc80g8/).

Comment: thank you for this, I am trying it now. Please tell me, does the code "hides" the actual content and shows the output only, or it rearrange it ?

Comment: It moves the elements, in order, into the result element.

Comment: I see, thank you again it works. In my use, I need to avoid using any extra div in the html code, so is there any way not to have the #result ?

Comment: Sure - you can use the parent element of the sections (if there is nothing else in it). See this variation here: http://jsfiddle.net/0f2abskc/